# Stage changes in file below a certain line number

Tags: git, git-add, git-stage

I made two sets of changes in a single file.
They are conceptually different so I would like to keep them in seperate commits.

Can I **stage the changes** in a **certain range** or **everything above or a below a line** from the command line?

I.e. something like the following:

```
git add file -lines 124:421
```

Comment: `git commit --interactive`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use git add -p and then select the hunks ou wish to add.

These are the options you can do within `add -p`:

```
y - stage this hunk
n - do not stage this hunk
q - quit, do not stage this hunk nor any of the remaining ones
a - stage this and all the remaining hunks in the file
d - do not stage this hunk nor any of the remaining hunks in the file
g - select a hunk to go to
/ - search for a hunk matching the given regex
j - leave this hunk undecided, see next undecided hunk
J - leave this hunk undecided, see next hunk
k - leave this hunk undecided, see previous undecided hunk
K - leave this hunk undecided, see previous hunk
s - split the current hunk into smaller hunks
e - manually edit the current hunk
? - print help
```

Once you use the `s` it will pick the chunk of code which can be considered as a standalone change. If you want to split it even more you will have to use the `e` to edit the hunk and then add it back to the stage area.

#### Summary:

To split hunks you use the `s` flag.
If you need to split it into even smaller chunks you will need to manually edit it using the `e` option.

[image]